# Best fit a circle from a binary image using contours or any other technique

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I've have a binary image computed from some algorithms. There is a hole in the image and I want to best fit a circle in this hole. I tried using `bestminEnclosingCircle` function but it don't give best results.

Here is binary image

[image]

Here is what I get from this function

[image]

Here is what expected

[image]

I want to exclude this part

[image]

Here is my code for finding contours

```
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;


    findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: your results looks weird for doing only findcontours... with that function you should be able to get the black blob completely... you can try fitellipse. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) is a tutorial of some of the opencv functions that may help you (it is in python, but the functions exist in c++ as well)

Answer (score 0):

check the code below

[image]

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat src, src_gray;

    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread("e:/test/ifFz9.png");
    resize(src, src, Size(), 0.25, 0.25);

    /// Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

    imshow("Source", src);

    Mat threshold_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    /// Detect edges using Threshold
    threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, 127, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    /// Find contours
    findContours(threshold_output, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if (contours[i].size() > 50)
        {
            RotatedRect minEllipse = fitEllipse(contours[i]);

            int size = min(minEllipse.size.width, minEllipse.size.height) / 2;
            // ellipse
            if (size < src.rows / 2)
                ellipse(src, minEllipse.center, Size(size, size), 0, 360, 0, Scalar(0, 0, 0255), 2, 8);
        }
    }

    imshow("Contours", src);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. Also, can you explain the second loop?

Comment: This is not give right results for this kind of image [binary](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxP3s-9QVdsEUlJlYUZiSWJSZjQ) [rgb result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxP3s-9QVdsEWUhPa18xQ2oyUTQ)

Comment: It also won't give right results if the hole is more white inside rather then ouside. i-e for this kind of example, we have to find max of the height and width of rotated rect instead of min of height and width.